# Redirect nginx config server_name to custom 404 error page

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm new to nginx configs and have spent a lot of time googling so far. I'm trying to create a very basic nginx config file to be used in a "redirect" server.

Users will be required to point naked domains (example.com) by A-record to my redirect server IP address, and the 'www' record by CNAME to another server.

The purpose of the redirect server is to then perform a 301 redirect any/wildcard naked domains back to to the 'www' version of the domain so it can be properly handled by my other server.

But I also want to catch any misconfigured 'www' domains that are pointing to my server IP by A-record, and simply direct them to a custom error page on the redirect server with further instructions on how to set up their account correctly for my service.

Here's what I have. **It works**, but since I am new to writing configs I was wondering if there is a better way to handle the redirect to the custom error page in the first server block. TIA!

```
#redirect to error page if begins with 'www.'

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^www.; #only matches if starts with 'www.'. Is this good enough?
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /404.html; #is this the correct way to direct to a custom error page?

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location  = /404.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
       }
    }

#no match, so redirect to www.example.com

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://www.$host$1 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prefix/suffix server name matching is [faster and easier than regexp](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#optimization).

Also, there is no reason to use rewrite. You want to return 404, so do it and nginx will do all the rest. BTW, with rewrite you will return `200 OK` with content of `/404.html` instead of `404 Not Found`.

So here it is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.*;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location / {
        return 404;
    }

    location = /404.html {
        internal;
    }
}
```